# I get error "invalid error at os.chdir(saved_path)" in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

```
#importing the os library 
    import os 
#Defining a function called rename_files()    
    def rename_files():

        #**get file names from a folder**
        file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\webdev\prank")
#Knowing about current working directory
        saved_path = os.getcwd()
        print("Current Working Directory is " +saved_path)
#changing the directory
        os.chdir(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\webdev\prank")

        #**for each file, rename filename**
#using For loop to change the name for each file name
        for file_name in file_list:
            os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None,"0123456789")
#saving back to current working directory
        os.chdir(saved_path)
#calling the function
    rename_files()
```

I am getting this error:

> invalid error at os.chdir(saved_path)

I'm using Python 3.6.

Comment: update question with stack trace

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I believe the error message that you actually got was `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` (as @FujiClado spotted). Especially if you need a rapid response, take care to report the *exact* error message you get because carelessness of this sort will cause some volunteers to shrug and move on.

Answer (score 0):

**I think You are missing a closing parenthesis.**

```
#importing the os library 
    import os 
#Defining a function called rename_files()    
    def rename_files():

        #**get file names from a folder**
        file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\webdev\prank")
#Knowing about current working directory
        saved_path = os.getcwd()
        print("Current Working Directory is " +saved_path)
#changing the directory
        os.chdir(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\webdev\prank")

        #**for each file, rename filename**
#using For loop to change the name for each file name
        for file_name in file_list:
            os.rename(file_name,file_name.translate(None,"0123456789") ) <<<<<== Here
#saving back to current working directory
        os.chdir(saved_path)
#calling the function
    rename_files()
```